# Ensemble Learning using Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, conv-neural-network, ensemble-learning

I have created 22 different Convolutional neural networks that all test for the presence of unique objects in an image (each one of the classifiers is unique).

Each sample in the test set has the output of a 22-long vector that looks something like this [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, ..., 1], the binary nature of the vector representing the presence/absence of specific objects.

I have implemented this already in keras and reach around 97% accuracy avg for the 22 models. Is there any specific ensemble methods that can allow me to combine all 22 classifiers?

Comment: You should compute accuracy for a single prediction, which is the average of models, not take average of accuracies.

Answer (score 0):

You can pop the softmax layers from your 22 networks, then you can use `keras.layers.Average()` or `keras.layers.Maximum()` for fusing these vectors.